# How to set default 'link'-attribute as 'media' in gallery-block in new editor (Gutenberg)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

When I add gallery in post the default value of `link` attribute is `none`. I want `media` (or `mediafile`, I don't know how is right) value as default. Documentation says me nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your gutenberg script:

```
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'my-theme/modify-linkTo-default',
    function (settings, name) {
        if (name !== 'core/gallery') {
            return settings;
        }

        settings.attributes.linkTo.default = 'media';

        return settings;
    }
);
```